# Rviz is stop - need some help

Tags: rviz, transform, ros-groovy, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all!

I have Ubuntu 12.04, Groovy. I launch openni_launch and rviz
I have a problem with Rviz. When I add pointcloud2, rviz is stop and update one per two second. but i haven't any errors.

What is wrong? maybe it is tf?

**Update1**

Also I have warn message:

```
[ WARN] [1392574116.780493741]: TF exception:
Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 1392574116.741091059 but the latest data is at time 1392574116.679388999, when looking up transform from frame [/camera_depth_optical_frame] to frame [/camera_rgb_optical_frame]
```

and I found this topic   http://answers.ros.org/question/12930/dropped-sensor-messages-in-navigation-stack/
maybe  improper timestamps relevant for my case? but I can't check it.

This TF error in openni.launch file?

**Update2**

I am use intel core i7.

```
PID USER        PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND            
19715 max       20   0 2085m 551m  63m R   82 18.3   1:04.19 rviz               
19475 max       20   0 1543m  65m  22m S   74  2.2   0:44.53 nodelet
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/129601/rviz-is-stop---need-some-help/) by [seredin](https://answers.ros.org/users/8936/seredin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2014-02-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-16**:
What is the CPU usage on your computer while rviz is running?

**Comment by [seredin](https://answers.ros.org/users/8936/seredin/) on 2014-02-16**:
I am use intel core i7.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-16**:
It looks like rviz is consuming most of a core. Do you have a dedicated graphics card, or are you using software OpenGL rendering?

**Comment by [seredin](https://answers.ros.org/users/8936/seredin/) on 2014-02-17**:
I am use OpenGL.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-17**:
Doing a minor editing to your question just to push it to the top of the queue is bad form.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-17**:
You still haven't stated if you have a dedicated graphics card or not.

**Comment by [seredin](https://answers.ros.org/users/8936/seredin/) on 2014-02-18**:
I am sorry for my push.
No. I haven't a dedicated graphics card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This sounds like either there isn't enough network bandwidth, or your computer is too slow to display point clouds.

Running the system monitor application (GUI) or top (command line) should show the system CPU usage, which will give you some hints about where the problem is.

Rendering point clouds is pretty graphics-intensive. You may be able to squeeze a little more performance out of your system by switching the rendering style.

I suspect the tf issues you're seeing are due to buffering and lag issues caused by how long it takes for your computer to render a single point cloud.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [seredin](https://answers.ros.org/users/8936/seredin/) on 2014-02-18**:
How I can change rendering style?

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-18**:
http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/DisplayTypes/PointCloud